# how to clone Movieclip by Java script

Tags: createjs

i try to clone Movie clip that contain motion and graphics by java script 
i have the following error: Uncaught Movie Clip cannot be cloned.
I wonder how this is accomplished?

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/MovieClip.html#method_clone):

> MovieClip instances cannot be cloned.